# how much php comfortable with Oracle

Tags: php, oracle

IS php is Comfortable with ORACLE?I have an experience of `PHP + mysql`, now, i want to move to Oracle is it right decision from my side to learn oracle ?

Comment: Languages such as PHP don't have distinct databases they "prefer", what database you use is meaningless for PHP itself as long as it has a driver that enables it to communicate with it. Btw. you can google answers to these questions rather than open topics at SO.

Comment: @Michael J.V. Well, almost. I can say that the driver for MySQL has been developed longer, and better than any other driver available in PHP. There has always been a strong cohesion between MySQL and PHP.

Comment: Also, the dream of *"seemlessly"* use any driver is a kind of dream. When applications grows, you have to mix PDO and raw SQL, using powerfull yet not-standard DBMS features to maintain performance, thus coupling (even a little) the application to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm currently working on a PHP+Oracle project. There is 2 way to use an oracle DB using PHP :

- [`php_oci`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.oci8.php) : like `php_mysql`, it's a set of procedural functions, with no OO design. You'll have to create your own classes. **But** it's the only way that is not experimental/is safe.
- [`pdo_oci`](http://php.net/manual/fr/ref.pdo-oci.php) : the `PDO` driver for Oracles databases. As described in the man page, it is **highly experimental** and I can testify about that. It keep having strange behavior : infinite fetch, crash, memory overflow. Definitely not usable on a professional context.

IMO, from a developper point of view, one DBMS or another isn't really important, unless you really use the guts ot the DBMS. If I were you, I'd focus on learning another language, bases on a nother paradigm than PHP, like Erlang or Scala, maybe Java if you want to focus on OO design. That would teach you more things than trying another DB

After all, database are only there to persist the data when the application shuts down!

Edit: I would add that Oracle (and Oracle ecosystem) are widely used in big company, especially in the industry. If you'd like to work in that sector, then Oracle might be a good choice.

Comment: ) I want to do Oracle because of job only, always asked by the eomployer

Comment: Are you sure you employer asks you to learn Oracle database, or Oracle Applications ? Because that really not the same =)

Comment: ) other employers with .net right now i m working in PHP and PostgreSQL but whenever i want to change the job mainly openings for java, .net, and oracle in database

Comment: ) can You please tel me about oracle certification? as i m the begineer in oracle but i want to certified for an Good job opportunity

Comment: I don't know anything about Oracle certifications, I'm just actually developping a PHP app, backed up with an Oracle DB. But I'm sure someone else here might help you.

Answer (score 0):

> IS php is Comfortable with ORACLE?I have an experience of PHP + mysql, now, i want to move to Oracle is it right decision from my side to learn oracle ?

Yes, PHP is "comfortable" with Oracle. That's to say; using PDO, you can pretty much do everything you want from within PHP. In regards to moving to Oracle; you could, but I understand license fees are pretty darn high, so you might want to consider moving to another Open Source database? I have good experiences with [PostgreSQL](http://postgresql.org), which is as advanced as Oracle, but open source.

Comment: @Berry Langerak:) ya right now i m working with PostgreSQL ...PDO (PHP data object extension) can You please tell me something about PDO?

Comment: PDO_OCI for oracle isn't stable not really usable, as it's still on beta/alpha.

Comment: PDO is an OO abstraction for database. You pick a driver, and you use the same code to query/use every database system seemlessly.

Comment: @Clement, sorry to say, but that's rubbish. First of all, PostgreSQL doesn't know of GROUP_CONCAT like MySQL does. Second of all, PostgreSQL uses sequences rather than auto_increment, which have to be handled differently. PDO doesn't abstract the database, it provides a uniform layer to use it.

Comment: Hum, you're absolutely right, I didn't chose the right word. Indeed it's not an abstraction, but a uniform layer (which is very close).

Comment: @Clement PDO_OCI isn't stable? Didn't know that, sorry. If it isn't stable, the OCI8 extension seems to be.

Comment: Yup, it's written in the `PDO_OCI` page. But `OCI8` isn't OO, so I tried `PDO_OCI` anyway, but it's really not production ready :/. Had to build my own OO wrapper aroung `OCI8`.

Comment: @Clement: Well, if you've already built the OO wrapper; is that open source? :)

Comment: @Berry Langerak:) absolutely right PDO provides interface for accessing Database-A Data-Access Abstration layer

Comment: @Berry unfortunately no, it belong to the company I'm working in. But I guess there must be 254343236zillions of oracle OO wrappers out there